# How to write a shell script which updates numbers +1 when run?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to write a shell script which echo's numbers when run

1st time ./x 1

2nd time ./x 2

3rd time ./x 3

after restarting the machine

./x 4

Comment: Basically you store the number into a file, but be careful, since you may have a race condition, if two instances of your script run concurrently: Since the update needs to be done atomic, synchronizing can be tricky. Read about file locking before writing your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to persist the last run into a file, in this case a `.persist` file in your home directory:

```
# Go into home directory to persist data.

cd "${HOME}"

# Get persisted data, make zero if empty/non-numeric/restart.

lastNum="$(cat .persist.dat 2> /dev/null)"
[[ -z "${lastNum}" ]] && lastNum=0
[[ "${lastNum}" =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]] || lastNum=0
[[ "$1" = "--restart" ]] && lastNum=0

# Add one, write to persistent file, and echo.

((lastNum += 1))
echo ${lastNum} > .persist.dat
echo ${lastNum}
```

As you can see, the output is an increasing value:

```
pax:~> ./x
1
pax:~> ./x
2
pax:~> ./x
3
pax:~> ./x
4
pax:~> ./x
5
pax:~> ./x --restart
1
```

Provided you don't delete the `.persist` file (or modify it so it contains an invalid integer), it should faithfully work, even across reboots. You'll notice I've also added a `--restart` flag so you can restart the sequence if desired.